# Artificial Intelligence In Ethereum Smart Contracts

Tags: artificial-intelligence, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I have been working with Ethereum smart contracts for a while for DAPP developments, recently i grew interest in working with Smart Contracts for Artificial intelligence. I found some work on net but it is not completely relevant to my idea. I actually want to have AI technique coded inside smart contract and perform prediction. I know that running AI inside smart contract would cost a ton but i would like to explore the field. I am still wondering why there has been very less work done in this field. Can anyone help me on that please.

Answer (score 1):

1. What practical problem do you want to solve with the help of AI in blockchain?
2. When using a rule graph (tree), AI may well be implemented in the Ethereum smart
   contract, although the cost of loading the rules graph can be quite significant.
3. When using DLT platforms with smart contracts in native languages (Hyper Ledger Fabric, EOSIO, Corda and so on), you can easily implement any AI techniques.
4. For DLT platforms with the execution of smart contracts on virtual machines (Ethereum, Quorum), you can use the Oracles methodology also without limiting the capabilities of AI.

Comment: I understand that Ethereum would take lot of gas for implementation and transactions, i was looking for applications that requires automation of AI and Blockchain can help  without a third party intervention. Also blockchain adds immutability that adds security to the AI results.

Comment: The problem with current smart contracts is that they do not support floating point numbers which limits prediction accuracy. I looked at some of the fixed point implementations but was not convinced with any.

Answer (score 0):

> I actually want to have AI technique coded inside smart contract and perform prediction.

This is not possible with current Ethereum technology, because of limitations what and how much code smart contracts can execute. There is no point of doing work in a field that is impossible and impractical.

Comment: We were actually looking for possible areas to explore in Ethereum. If at all there is work around to perform AI in smart contracts.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you try to do makes little sense from technical and commercial perspective.